# Реализовать мониторинг логов Nginx(Apache) в Zabbix

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, zabbix

Основная проблема заключается в том что на разных серверах файлы имеют разное название, на некоторых `error.log` а на других `aza_error.log`, каким образом можно было бы реализовать мониторинг, прописывать каждый мне кажется глупо, а `*error.log` не работает.

Comment: а `.*error.log` тоже не работает?

Comment: @PotroNik К сожалению тоже не работает.

Comment: В таком случае я думаю нужно более детально описать проблему, указать версию zabbix и метод проверки. Нажмите править и добавьте информацию.

Comment: Попробовал  
logrt[/var/log/nginx/.*error.log] Вывел какие то данные, но что то не то с кодировкой(иероглифы)